# Legendre polynomials basis

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Is there a possibility to show that the normalised Legendre polynomials are an orthonormal basis on $L^2([-1,1])$ by using directly Stone Weierstass approx theorem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The Legendre polynomials are a basis of all polynomials. By Weierstraß, polynomials are dense in the continuous functions, and by smoothing kernels the continuous functions are dense in the Lebesgue spaces.

So yes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Can you please say some more words to "smoothing kernels"? I've never heard of it

Comment: Take some non-negative continuous function $\phi$ with compact support and integral $1$. Define $\phi_n(x)=n\phi(nx)$, $n\in\Bbb N$. Then the convolution products $\phi_n*f$ are continuous for any integrable function $f$ and converge to $f$ in any $L^p$ space that $f$ belongs to.

Comment: I dont see how these kernels would help me by proving the problem...

Comment: any suggestions? :)